# regular expression to remove the file name from the full url

Tags: javascript, regex

With this code I will get the full path of the executed script, in this case `services.js`:

**JS**

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;

alert(src);
```

Output example:

```
file:///C:/Users/fel/Desktop/currencies-gh-pages/js/services.js
```

But i want an output like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/fel/Desktop/currencies-gh-pages/js/
```

Any idea?

Comment: Performance test here -> http://jsperf.com/replace-speed-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could split it instead.

```
src = src.split('/');
src.pop();
alert(src.join('/'));
```

Comment: `"regular expression to remove the file name from the full url"`, I don't see any regex in this =P

Comment: @plalx - why would you use regex when you don't have to !

Comment: there's plenty of solutions proposed here :). I'm trying to being as fast as possible. Could even use `src.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')`

Comment: @adeneo, Maybe the OP wanted to know how it's done with a regex..., however I agree that it's good to show alternative solutions ;)

Comment: @user1737909, I created a performance test here  http://jsperf.com/replace-speed-test

Comment: Note, fails with URLs like this: `http://example.com`. Note the missing slash after the host. Will produce `http://`. Use this regex (with negative lookahead): `/\/(?!\/\/)/` instead of the string `'/'`.

Answer (score 1):

> "regular expression to remove the file name from the full url"

You could replace all the chars that arent `/` at the end of the string using the following regex `/[^\/]+$/`.

```
src.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '');
```

However, it seems to be the slower solution compared to some other solutions: http://jsperf.com/replace-speed-test

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://phpjs.org/functions/dirname/

```
var txt = 'file:///C:/Users/fel/Desktop/currencies-gh-pages/js/services.js';

function dirname (path) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Ozh
  // +   improved by: XoraX (http://www.xorax.info)
  // *     example 1: dirname('/etc/passwd');
  // *     returns 1: '/etc'
  // *     example 2: dirname('c:/Temp/x');
  // *     returns 2: 'c:/Temp'
  // *     example 3: dirname('/dir/test/');
  // *     returns 3: '/dir'
  return path.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\/[^\/]*\/?$/, '');
}

alert(dirname(txt));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src.slice(0, src.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJYTm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```